# Too many Cassandra processes on the server

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

The following is the screenshot of htop on my dev server [arranged by MEM% used]:
[image]

I have only one cassandra instance running, but there are so many cassandra processes in htop, which is taking up 16 gb of ram.

The server is not being used in production, hence there are no queries being run on it at the moment.

I don't understand the reason why so many cassandra processes are running on my system, and how can I control this. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra is a greedy process, It wont leave the RAM unless asked for.

You do not need to worry about the used RAM. If any other process will request for RAM, Cassandra process will leave the RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra typically can take upto 16 GB RAM, which is the minimum prod recommendation from a performance point of view. Along with Cassandra there are a number of other processes which get the memory allocation like the JVM heap here. And as mentioned above it is a memory intensive technology.